# Tizen doesn't launch deviceready event

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I would like to use the accelerometer on my samsung gear pro 2 so I am following this guide:
https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/development/guides/web-application/cordova/device-motions?langredirect=1#values

I'm still at the first step, it does not enter the "deviceready" event, this is my code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log('Cordova features now available');
    }

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);    
}; 

function onDeviceReady1() {
    console.log('Cordova features now available');
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady1, false);
```

in console i never read "Cordova features now available"

Comment: In your Gear Pro, what is the Tizen version ? and what is your project API version ?

Comment: in gear pro i read "se for tizen 1.0" i hope is the right info, and the config is: 
<widget xmlns="*****" xmlns:tizen="*****" id="*****" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized">
    <tizen:application id="****" package="*******" required_version="2.3"/>

Comment: That is your project configuration ...you set 2.3 for your project 
What is your Gear OS version ?

Comment: i don't know. how can i check it?

Comment: Please check on Settings > About Gear > Software Information > Tizen Version

Comment: Sorry the delay, i don't found this info, but i think is 2.3.1 (from: https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/general-support/tizen-os-version-on-gear-fit-2?langswitch=ko)

Comment: Dependencies :Tizen 3.0 and Higher for Wearable
Then this api won't work on your device
https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/development/guides/web-application/cordova/device-motions?langredirect=1

Comment: you are right! Is there a way to get data from the Accelerator on previous versions?
even when the device has the screen turned off?

Comment: You can force the device to turn on the device or request CPU Awake